# Automator workflow triggered by another app?

Tags: automator

Is it possible to trigger an Automator workflow/application when a specific action occurs in another application? I want to trigger the Automator script to play a particular track in iTunes when my Pomodoro work timer finishes.

If not possible can anyone recommend any other solutions? (please treat with kid gloves as am not a developer)

thnkx

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish your goal? We're here to help you solve problems, but we need to know what you've tried to do, but failed. You might want to take a look at **[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com)** as a starting point.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I've tried using Automator. Searching for an answer on how to get Automator to do what I require. Searching for alternative apps. IFTTT doesn't have a BeFocused integration available as far as i can see

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need an API for the pomodoro app that you're using. The only other way this could be created is by looking for any change instantiated on your native os when the timer is done. Then create an apple script which watches for the identified trigger and plays the sound bite you want when this trigger to call on the custom apple script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How would I look for a change instantiated in OSX when the timer has ended. Do I need to look in a log somewhere for this?

Comment: I would look into using the Activity Monitor program on your mac. Again my method only works if you know how to create your own Apple Script to link your Automator function to the BeFocused action. Also I just checked out the site for BeFocused and it seems like if you upgrade to the Pro version of the app setting your own song is just a simple setting.